# Android: Receiving wrong UTM from Google Ads

Tags: android, firebase, ads, utm-tracking

According to my boss, some of our applications have been invested on advertising of the app via Google Ads. In order for them to parse the data and analyze them correctly, they are using the UTM auto-tagging approach. It is my job from the client (Android Device) to send the UTM using Firebase Analytics and also a custom event to Firebase depending on this UTM.

However, our data shows that both Firebase SDK and our events are transferred incorrectly. The click numbers and the download numbers do not match. Since both of them are incorrect, I'm guessing the received UTM on the device itself is wrong, and this needs to be received correctly and I am unable to find an answer for this.

I'm using [Install Referrer Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library) to track down what the UTM is after the app is downloaded to the device. I am guessing Firebase SDK also uses somewhat similar approach. On our end, the UTM is recorded to `SharedPreferences` and it is not queried again if the query was successful.

Here is the related code for it (the `processReferrer` method basically parses the UTM according to our needs):

```
/**
 * Checks if the referrer information is recorded before, if not, creates
 * a connection to Google Play and saves the data to shared preferences.
 */
private static void fetchReferrerInformation(Context context)
{
    SharedPreferences preferences =
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String utmData = preferences.getString(UTM_DATA, "");

    // Only connect if utm is not recorded before.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(utmData))
    {
        InstallReferrerClient client;

        try
        {
            client = InstallReferrerClient.newBuilder(context).build();
            client.startConnection(new InstallReferrerStateListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onInstallReferrerSetupFinished(int responseCode)
                {
                    switch (responseCode)
                    {
                        case InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.OK:
                        {
                            ReferrerDetails response;
                            try
                            {
                                response = client.getInstallReferrer();
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Error while fetching referrer information.", e);
                                if (Fabric.isInitialized())
                                    Crashlytics.logException(new IllegalStateException("Exception while fetching UTM information.", e));
                                return;
                            }
                            if (response != null)
                            {
                                processReferrer(context, response.getInstallReferrer());
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        case InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED:
                        {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Install referrer client: Feature is not supported.");
                            break;
                        }
                        case InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Install referrer client: Service is unavailable.");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        client.endConnection();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ignored){}
                }

                @Override
                public void onInstallReferrerServiceDisconnected()
                {
                    // Do nothing, we need to fetch the information once and
                    // it is not really necessary to try to reconnect.
                    // If app is opened once more, the attempt will be made anyway.
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (Fabric.isInitialized())
                Crashlytics.logException(new IllegalStateException("Exception while fetching UTM information.", e));
        }
    }
    else
        Log.i(TAG, "UTM is already recorded, skipping connection initialization. Value: " +
                utmData);
}
```

The approach is pretty simple, however the data seems to be wrong. So, does it seem that the implementation is somewhat incorrect? If not, why is the data received from Google Ads is wrong? Any help is appreciated, thank you very much.

Edit: Upon some testing, here is what I've found:

**Works:**

An API 19 real device (GM Discovery II Mini) and in between API 25-29 emulators with Play Store installed. Edit: UTM can also be fetched with API 23 and 24 Genymotion Emulators, where Play Store is installed.

**Doesn't work:**

An API 24 Android Studio emulator with latest Google Play Services and Play Store installed (device is also logged in to my account), and **a real device** (General Mobile 4G Dual, API 23) cannot query the UTM information. The code below lands on the case of `InstallReferrerResponse.FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED`. So I am almost sure that the install referrer client is bugged on some API levels.

Edit: Opened an issue to the Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149342702

Comment: May I ask what the instant downvote is for?

Comment: Can we see processReferrer() ? Also, how much is the difference between Google Ads report and Firebase Analytics?

Comment: @RishabhSagar Unfortunately I'm not allowed to share the `processReferrer()` method but the error basically comes from `response.getInstallReferrer()`. I am sure of it, because with the old system where the broadcast receiver was used, it was working flawlessly.

Comment: I added an answer. It might not be the exact answer you want. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60188740/3948854

Comment: Any solution so far? It seems that the tracking of Google Ads campaigns for Android apps differs from the officially recommended utm_source/utm_medium.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know how you are processing the resonse, I can show you the way we did it in our implementation.

```
ReferrerDetails response = referrerClient.getInstallReferrer();
if (response == null) {
    break;
}

String[] installReferrer = response.getInstallReferrer().split("&");

if (installReferrer.length >= 1) {
    utmSource = installReferrer[0].split("=")[1];
} 
if (installReferrer.length >= 2) {
    utmMedium = installReferrer[1].split("=")[1];
}
```

Compare this snippet with yours and check if anything differs.

Comment: Unfortunately the `response.getInstallReferrer()` method returns a wrong value in this case. That's why the string you parsed would be actually wrong too with this method. So, I'm afraid this is not the solution.

Comment: Hey @FurkanYurdakul,  I think it might be an issue with the tracking URL format you are using in Google Ads. Did you tried using this tool to build the tracking URL https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-url-builder . Also, compare the URL generated by this tool with the current URL.

Comment: Hmm. If that is the case I guess Google Ads itself is generating wrong values then? Because upon manual creation and redirection the UTM is fetched correctly. Did you encounter anything like it before?

Comment: We never tried measuring Google Ads install, but we do have implemented a referral system which requires the creation of a referral link(something similar which I referred in the above comment). With that, we were able to track the actual source from where the user installs the App. If I'm not wrong, I remember we can provide tracking URL while creating Ads in Google Ads Dashboard. You can give it a try.